# Spark Dataset createOrReplaceTempView ViewName restrictions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Call `createOrReplaceTempView` on Spark Dataset with "123D" as name of the view and get:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Invalid view name: 123D;

Whereas with parameter "123Z" everything is Ok.

Is there any restrictions on parameter of `createOrReplaceTempView`?

Spark version: 2.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trailing `D` after a number has a special meaning which indicates that the preceding number should be of double type. See the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-literals.html#numeric-literal) for a list of possible letters, including L, S, Y, D, F, BD.

It's perhaps not a good practice to name your views/tables like that, but if you really want to do it, you can add backticks, e.g.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('`123D`')
```

And you also need to add backticks when you do a select, e.g.

```
spark.sql("select * from `123D`")
```